# Configure CUPS permissions

Tags: permissions, printing

I'm trying to install a printer through CUPS, but I am unable to.

I get up to the point where I need to log in to the CUPS interface, but I keep getting a `403 Forbidden` message when I try to use my credentials.

How do I log in and install my printer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's wrong with installing a printer [the normal way](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/printing-setup.html)?

From the linked page:

> 1. Open System Settings from the Dash.
> 2. Open Printers.
> 3. Click Add and select the printer from the Devices window. If it's a network printer, you may need to manually configure it.
> 4. Click Forward and wait while it searches for drivers.
> 5. You can customize the printer's name, description, and location if you
>      like. When finished, click Apply.
> 6. You can now print a test page or click Cancel to skip that step.

If you want to use CUPS (the thing at [`https://localhost:631`](https://localhost:631)), you need to make sure your user is part of the `lpadmin` group. To do this, run this command in a terminal:

```
sudo usermod -aG lpadmin <your_username>
```

Be sure to replace `<your_username>` with your username. After this command has run, be sure to reboot or log out of every active session.

Then, log into the CUPS interface using your Linux credentials.

Comment: I have been very helpful to your answer. Problem solved. Thank you very much for your answer.